# How to make nested table scrollable in mobile with Overflow: scroll without jerk

Tags: css, sass

I have tried to make nested tables scrollable in mobile responsive, when browser loads initially tables are jerking for 5 seconds after that it works fine.

I tried overflow touch scroll to child table and added same to parent div but not working. please anyone help me on this.

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) and (min-device-width: 320px) {
  .panel-information {
    overflow: scroll;
    display: block;
    height: 60%;
  }
  .price-box-heads {
    overflow: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-information">
  <table class="panel-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" class="price-box-heads">
            <thead targetattr="heads">
              <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Public</td>
                <td>Priority</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 5</td>
                <td>Cruise Line Discount</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Offer</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>8 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Amount</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" class="price-box-heads">
            <thead targetattr="heads">
              <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Public</td>
                <td>Priority</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 5</td>
                <td>Cruise Line Discount</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Offer</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>8 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Amount</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" class="price-box-heads">
            <thead targetattr="heads">
              <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Public</td>
                <td>Priority</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 5</td>
                <td>Cruise Line Discount</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Offer</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>8 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Amount</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" class="price-box-heads">
            <thead targetattr="heads">
              <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Public</td>
                <td>Priority</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 5</td>
                <td>Cruise Line Discount</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Offer</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>8 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Amount</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `max-device-width` and `min-device-width` with simply `max-width` and `min-width`:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }

  .panel-information {
    overflow: scroll;
    display: block;
    height: 60%;
  }

  .price-box-heads {
    overflow: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-information">
  <table class="panel-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" class="price-box-heads">
            <thead targetattr="heads">
              <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Public</td>
                <td>Priority</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 5</td>
                <td>Cruise Line Discount</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Offer</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>8 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Amount</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" class="price-box-heads">
            <thead targetattr="heads">
              <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Public</td>
                <td>Priority</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 5</td>
                <td>Cruise Line Discount</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Offer</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>8 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Amount</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" class="price-box-heads">
            <thead targetattr="heads">
              <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Public</td>
                <td>Priority</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 5</td>
                <td>Cruise Line Discount</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Offer</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>8 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Amount</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" class="price-box-heads">
            <thead targetattr="heads">
              <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Public</td>
                <td>Priority</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td> 5</td>
                <td>Cruise Line Discount</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>6 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Offer</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>8 </td>
                <td>Cruise Line Amount</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: After browser loading 5 seconds I con't able scroll till end

Comment: @Anitha What do you mean by that ? The code just makes the table scrollable and nothing else. By testing the code snippet you will see that you can scroll. So the problem doesn't come from here.